# How do I set system wide proxy in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: networking, 18.04, proxy

There is no 'Apply System Wide' option.I have to manually change /etc/apt/apt.conf file every time I set or unset proxy.

How do I configure it so that it applies system wide proxy settings - with apt.conf updating accordingly in Ubuntu 18.04?

**EDIT**:

Despite setting apt.conf manually, I'm not able to install anything through Ubuntu Software because an "Unsupported proxy configured: proxy.server.com//8080" error comes up. How do I fix this?

Comment: Bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1730672 You might want to add yourself as being affected.

Comment: You have to specifiy `http://` in front of the hostname, everything else irritates apt

Answer (score 8):

Set proxy details in Environment variables;
Edit `/etc/environment` and add following lines (replace username, password, host and port with your proxy details).

```
http_proxy=http://username:password@host:port/
ftp_proxy=ftp://username:password@host:port/
https_proxy=https://username:password@host:port/
```

For apt,software center & etc;
edit `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/80proxy` (if its not exist create it) and add the following lines

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://username:password@host:port/";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://username:password@host:port/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://username:password@host:port/";
```

Comment: Is there anyway to automatically update /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/80proxy? I have to manually set it each time - in previous versions of Ubuntu, I needn't have done that - just clicking on the button 'Apply System Wide'  through GUI was good enough.

Comment: what is the Desktop Environment you use? Gnome?

Comment: check this for Gnome. but everytime you setting proxy you will need to type them in. [link](https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/administration-linux/how-to-configure-proxy-on-ubuntu-18-04/)

Comment: :) if you found answer mark it.

Comment: Despite setting apt.conf manually, I'm not able to install anything through Ubuntu Software because an "Unsupported proxy configured: proxy.server.com//8080" error comes up. How do I fix this?

Comment: did you configure proxy by using GUI?

Comment: Yes, and I followed your instructions too because while my environmental variables were set, the file 80proxy did not exist. It made no difference.

Comment: try with */etc/apt/apt.conf* instead of */etc/apt/apt.conf.d/80proxy*. check also man page of apt.conf by *man apt.conf*

Comment: I already have. It didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find any proxy information in `/etc/environment` even on `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/80proxy`, because I informed proxy value at setup.

I find it on this file: `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/90curtin-aptproxy`.

Answer (score 0):

18.04 uses GNOME as the default desktop manager, although I prefer Unity which was used in several previous LTS releases.  When I installed and switched to Unity, the "apply system wide" option was restored in the network/proxy settings menu.

To switch to Unity, run `sudo apt update && sudo apt install ubuntu-unity-desktop`, and select the `lightdm` option when prompted.  I had to first edit `/etc/environment` by hand to include my proxy server before apt could reach the repositories for the update/install.  [This link](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-unity-desktop-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux) gives a detailed description of how to switch to Unity.